# How to check geographic distance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

We currently use the following to work out any listings within a 10km radius. However we want to allow a business to say only show my business if within 2km.

Current

```
location:{ $geoWithin:{ $centerSphere: [ [ 115.76, -32.24], 10 / 6378.1] }
```

While this gives me the businesses in the 10km radius I now need to check if

`maxRadius` is is less than the business requires.

```
{
    "location": {
        "coordinates": [115.76019, -32.24711],
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "name": "DEMO BUSINESS - Kwinana",
    "maxRadius": 2
}
```

For example the above business is a business that only wants to be shown if the radius returned is less than 2km.

What is the best way to do this? I am trying to work this out in MongoDB Atlas and having issues getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `maxRadius` along with the `location` in the `.find()` query, and include only those businesses whose `maxRadius` is greater than or equal to `givenRadius`

```
.find({
   location: { 
       $geoWithin:{ 
           $centerSphere: [ [ 115.76, -32.24], givenRadius / 6378.1] 
       }
    },
    maxRadius: {$gte:givenRadius}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample collection data

```
{ 
"business": "Store",
"geo": {
    "name": "StoreName",
    "coordinates": [80.628913, 13.622177],
    "type": "Point"
},
"address": "Some Address",
"city": "Kolkata",
"pincode": "700001",
"startTime": "10:00:00 AM",
"closingTime": "7:00:00 PM",
"closedOn": "Closed on Sunday",}
```

Create 2dSphear index on `db.collectionName.createIndex({geo:'2dsphere'})`
Now use the $geoNear aggregation query to smoothly fetch record.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
       {
         $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [  80.3355,13.6701  ] }, // Mandatory Param.
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",          // It will return in the document how much distence (meter) is far feom center
            maxDistance: 2000,                         // Fetch 2KM radius store, Distance in meter from the center 
            spherical: true,                           // calculates distances using spherical geometry.
            query:{pincode:"700001"}                  // Specific Query parameter on other field present in the collection
         }
       }
    ]).pretty()
```

This is a working code and tested and verified.

Comment: The above works by creating a new field {dist:Object
calculated:791.679124125065} so can I leave maxDistance: 10000 and some how do a if gte exclude query - because in theory there maybe 10 listings that get returned.

Comment: 'maxDistance' --> Field you need to pass in meters for the radius you want.
'distanceField' --> This field will return to your query that how far each store is situate from your provided coordinate center.
'{ $limit: 10 }' use this for limiting 10 store else check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: Only 'near' and 'distanceField' are mandatory parameter, rest are optional, you can check whole list of parameter and example the link I provided in my previous comment.